# Threading: pause periodic updates of the object for the time it is deep-copied, Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety

The problem: on the thread `A` exists object, let's name it `origin` of arbitrary complex type. Every time message comes, `origin` get's updated accordingly. Changes might be quite comperhensive, being far from atomic operation. Meanwhile, on the thread `B` there is something like `origin_deep_copy = copy.deep_copy(origin)` happening periodically, which also isn't atomic. What's the classic approach to force thread `A` to wait when `B` will finish copy gracefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic approach would be to use a [Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) to guard access to the object.  That is, any time any thread wants to read or write the state of the shared object, the thread should first `acquire()` a Lock that you have created to guard that object.  Then the thread can do whatever it wants to the object, and when it's done, it should `release()` the Lock so that the next thread can have access to the object.  (Any `acquire()` call on that Lock object won't return until it is the calling thread's own "turn" to own the Lock and therefore access the shared object).

The obvious way to do it would look like this:

```
from threading import Lock

my_lock = Lock()  # usually this is done at program startup

[... later, in whatever thread...]
my_lock.acquire()
do_the_copy_of_the_shared_object()
my_lock.release()
```

... but there is a logically-equivalent syntax that is easier and safer (in that you don't have to worry about messing up and forgetting to call `release()` when you are done, or if an exception gets thrown while you have the Lock acquired):

```
from threading import Lock

my_lock = Lock()  # usually this is done at program startup

[... later, in whatever thread...]
with my_lock:
   do_the_copy_of_the_shared_object()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've expected to discover something different from good old `threading.Lock`. Something more specific for this particular problem.